# HTTP_CONNECTION and Apache + Nginix

Tags: php, nginx, apache2.4

Использую openserver на своём пк для разработки веб приложений.
В настройках могу выбирать:
 - apache
 - apache + nginix
При использовании только apache я вытягивают заголовок на своём сайте через $_SERVER["HTTP_CONNECTION"] => keep-alive.

При использовании apache + nginix я вытягивают заголовок на своём сайте через $_SERVER["HTTP_CONNECTION"] => close.

На сервер, который буду вылаживать свой сайт, используется apache + nginix.

моя цель сделать соеденение keep-alive.
Пробовал .htaccess добавить

Header set Connection keep-alive

Безрезультатно.
В браузере показывает connection => keep-alive,но в моем заголовке close.

Как сделать открытое соеденение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не совсем правильная интерпретация результатов.

В связке apache + nginx, клиент осуществляет соединение Keep-Alive  с nginx, если оно сконфигурировано (по умолчанию это так).

При этом вы видите close "на стороне" Apache/PHP, потому что nginx->apache не поддерживает keep-alive соединение если оно не сконфигурировано. Включать это особой необходимости не нужно, потому что keepalive соединение наиболее важно для клиент-сервер, а не сервер-сервер (программы находящиеся на сервере, обмениваются данными друг с другом быстро).

Если всё же хотите keepalive и в nginx->apache для микро-оптимизации, то это делается так

```
upstream your_apache {
  keepalive 100;

  server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}
server {
    location / {
      ...
      proxy_pass             http://your_apache;
      ...
    }
}
```